# Objective-C Memory Management Question, NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management

I have a UIViewController. At the top of the UIViewController, I have declared

```
NSMutableArray *contacts;
```

In my `viewDidLoad` method, I call `[self getContacts]` which basically initializes my `contacts` array. It begins by initializing the array, and then it adds some objects:

```
if(contacts == nil)
   contacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[contacts removeAllObjects];
[contacts addObjectsFromArray:[some objects]];
```

So, now my `contacts` is initialized. In my viewDidLoad method, I even use `contacts`, and it works great. Later on, in a method, I need to retrieve the elements of `contacts`, however I am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Why is this? Why doesn't my `contacts` array keep the objects that I initialized it with in the beginning, and how do I fix this?

EDIT:
The error comes when I select a NavigationBarItem which then triggers a method `buttonWasPressed`. In that method, I simply have the following:

```
-(void)buttonWasPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"button was pressed");
    if(contacts == nil)
       NSLog(@"contacts is nil!");

    NSLog(@"contacts = %@",contacts);
}
```

And I see "button was pressed" printed, but then there is an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: Please post the code of that method where you get bad access. Also when you add objects to array, it retains those objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code all looks good, nothing wrong there. I would guess you are over-releasing elsewhere. Turn on Zombies - add NSZombieEnabled to YES in the executable arguments and it will break on the line so you can see what object is being over-released.

Comment: how to I add NSZombieEnabled? where do I go in XCode to do this?

Comment: Expand Executables item in the Groups and Files list, double-click your executable, select the Arguments tab and add a value into the bottom window... Name - NSZombieEnabled  value YES

Comment: where is "Groups and Files list"?

Comment: On the left, I see my project name, I see "Targets", "Executables", "Find Results", "Bookmarsk", "SCM", "Project Symbols", "Implementation Files", and "Interface Builder Files"